# WP_Query custom post types with taxonomy not working

Tags: wordpress

I know this has been asked before, and I've searched, but I'm not finding the answer to my problem. I'm having an issue getting a custom post type with a custom taxonomy. If I use WP_Query without the `tax_query` parameter, it works fine and pulls in posts, but when I add `tax_query`, no posts are displayed. Since it works without it, I'm guessing there might be something not set up correctly in the admin, but that's just a guess. Here's what I'm currently trying:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'cris-tales'
            )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
```

I've verified that the post type and tags are both valid and exist. If I go to this url `/news_tag/cris-tales/` the correct posts are there, so I know they're assigned properly as well.

The only thing that's out of the ordinary is that I'm pulling these posts from another site within a WP multi site by using `switch_to_blog()`, but like I previously said, if I omit the `tax_query` parameter it works, so I don't think that has anything to do with it.

So am I missing something?

**EDIT**
Here's the full query:

```
switch_to_blog( 1 );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'news_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'cris-tales'
            )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 3
);
$result = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $result-> have_posts() ) :
    while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post();
        echo '<h3><a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></h3>';
        echo '<p>'.get_the_excerpt().'</p>';
        echo '<small>'.get_the_date().'</small>';
    endwhile;
endif; wp_reset_postdata();

// set it back to other blog
switch_to_blog( 2 );
```

**EDIT 2**

So it appears that it DOES have to do with the `switch_to_blog()` function because I copied over the same code to the blog that I'm trying to pull from and it worked! Then I started searching and found this solution:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284514/tax-query-not-working-on-multisite

Apparently the custom types have to be registered on BOTH sites. No need to add terms, but just registered.

Comment: Could you add your full query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is  an issue with how [WordPress Multisite](https://wordpress.org/support/article/create-a-network/) handles taxonomies on a persite basis, and how the [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog) function works. Unfortunately, calling [`switch_to_blog()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog) doesn't **fully** switch you over liked you'd think, and there's still fragments from other functions and filters that can't/won't work as they would if called directly in that particular site.

Basically what's happening is that is that if the [`tax_query` parameters of `WP_Query()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) encounter an invalid or null taxonomy (or term) on that site, it will replace the `WHERE` clause in the SQL with  `0 = 1` to prevent anything from returning.

You'll find a few results around the web for terms like "`tax_query` not working on Multi-Site", as it's a Mult-Site specific issue.

This really leaves you with two options:

#### 1) Redundant Taxonomies

> Make sure that every taxonomy (and ideally, term) is added to **every** blog that will be a part of the "blog switching"

I don't like this, because it's not particularly scalable. Great if you need it on a blog or two or three, and even better if you're adding the taxonomies and terms programatically with functions like [`wp_insert_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term), but still leaves a lot to be desired when dealing with larger installations.

This is as simple as making sure all the sites (or at least, the Main Site and all the "switched to" sites) have the same taxonomies and terms in them. This can be done manually in the wp-admin or programatically in your `functions.php` file (or similar).

#### 2) Edit the WHERE clause directly

> Make use of the [`posts_where`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where) filter to edit the `WHERE` clause in the SQL pseudo-manually

I like this better because it prevents needing to retain an effectively useless set of duplicates, so this is the one I'll expand on.

If you were to `var_dump( $result->request )`, I'd wager you'd see something like this in it:

```
 AND ( 0 = 1 ) AND wp_123_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_123_posts.post_status = 'publish'))
```

The above would indicate an invalid taxonomy/term pairing, as what you'd expect to see would be something like:

```
 AND ( wp_123_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (3) ) AND wp_123_posts.post_type = 'post' AND ((wp_123_posts.post_status = 'publish'))"
```

Similarly, the `JOIN` would be empty instead of something like:

```
 LEFT JOIN wp_123_term_relationships ON (wp_123_posts.ID = wp_123_term_relationships.object_id)
```

The `posts_[…]` filters are exceptionally powerful in fixing some queries on the fly before they're run, and it makes some complex queries a lot easier.

One last issue is that even using `switch_to_blog` won't allow some functions like [`get_term_by()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by) to run properly. You can get around that though because it *does* change the global `$wpdb` to reflect the new blogs prefix, so you can do a simple SQL query for the desired taxonomy term.

Take the `posts_where` filter for example:

```
function filter_where( $where ){
    global $wpdb;

    $term = 'test-term';
    $tax  = 'text-tax';

    $term_sql = "
        SELECT {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id
        FROM   {$wpdb->prefix}terms
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy
               ON {$wpdb->prefix}terms.term_id = {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
        WHERE {$wpdb->prefix}terms.slug = %s
        AND   {$wpdb->prefix}term_taxonomy.taxonomy = %s
    ";
    $term_id = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare( $term_sql, array( $term, $tax ) ) );

    $where = " AND ( {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ({$term_id}) ) AND {$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_type = 'post' AND (({$wpdb->prefix}posts.post_status = 'publish'))";
    return $where;
}
```

And similarly, the [`posts_join`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_join) filter:

```
function filter_join( $join ){
    global $wpdb;
    $join = " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships ON ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = {$wpdb->prefix}term_relationships.object_id) ";
    return $join;
}
```

Doing this, and calling [`add_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter) and [`remove_filter()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter) before and after your query, should give you a starting point for not needing to maintain multiple copies of duplicate and useless taxonomy terms:

```
switch_to_blog(3); // Prevents needing to modify all aspects of the query

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'post',
        'orderby'     => 'date',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'order'       => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => 3
    );

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'filter_join' );
    $result = new WP_Query( $args );
    remove_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_where' );
    remove_filter( 'posts_join', 'filter_join' );

    if ( $result-> have_posts() ) :
        while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post();
            printf( '<h3><a href="%s">%s</a></h3>', esc_url(get_the_permalink()), get_the_title() );
            printf( '<p>%s</p>', get_the_excerpt() );
            printf( '<small>%s</small>', get_the_date() );
        endwhile;
    endif;

    // set it back to other blog
    switch_to_blog( 1 );
```

You can see an example here: https://xhynk.com/multisite/
I've set up a Multi-Site and only added the taxonomy and term `test-tax` and `test-term` on the [blog_id 3, /site-b](https://xhynk.com/multisite/site-b/), and am dumping the above functions into the `wp_head`. The taxonomy (and so of course, the term) are both **not** set anywhere else but on site-b.

---

#### Documentation & Function Reference

| Function | Linked Description |
| --- | --- |
| `add_filter()` | [Hook a function or method to a specific filter action.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter) |
| `wp_insert_term()` | [Add a new term to the database.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_term) |
| `posts_where` | [Filters the WHERE clause of the query.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where) |
| `posts_join` | [Filters the JOIN clause of the query.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_join) |
| `remove_filter()` | [Removes a function from a specified filter hook.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_filter) |
| `get_term_by()` | [Get all Term data from database by Term field and data.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by) |
| `switch_to_blog()` | [Switch the current blog.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/switch_to_blog) |
| `esc_url()` | [Checks and cleans a URL](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_url/) |

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed answer. That helps me better understand what's going on

Answer (score 0):

When using the `switch_to_blog()` function both sites need to have the custom taxonomies registered:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/284514/tax-query-not-working-on-multisite

The custom taxonomies only need to be registered. No need to add terms, but just registered on the secondary site. The primary site will hold all of the term data to query.